# Error while executing the c++ code

Tags: c++

```
class Fruit{

};

class Banana: public Fruit
{
    public:
    bool isRipe(){
        if (mColor == ‘y’){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};

main(){
    Banana banana;
    banana.setColor(‘y’);
    if(banana.isRipe()){
        cout << “banana is ready to eat” << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << “banana is not ready to eat” << endl;
    }
}
```

This is the code which needs to be compiled but throwing the below error:-

```
$\fruit.cpp||In member function 'bool Banana::isRipe()':|
$\fruit.cpp|17|error: 'y' was not declared in this scope|
$\fruit.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
$\fruit.cpp|28|error: 'class Banana' has no member named 'setColor'|
$\fruit.cpp|28|error: 'y' was not declared in this scope|
$\fruit.cpp|30|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
$\fruit.cpp|30|error: expected ';' before 'is'|
$\fruit.cpp|33|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
```

$\fruit.cpp|33|error: expected ';' before 'is'|
||=== Build failed: 32 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I am trying to use the base class for the given derived class of Fruit but not getting it right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the actual code, as well as the error. How are we supposed to guess what's wrong if we don't have either ?

Comment: _not getting it right_ isn't very useful to go on. What is the expected output, and what is the current output? You also seem to be missing a declaration/definition of `setColor`, although presumably it's in the `Fruit` class.

Comment: why would you want to derive from a blank class. formatting makes me want to cry :'(

Comment: Where is `mColor` defined? Where is the function `setColor` defined? Do you mean `std::cout` and `std::endl`? Oh, also don't use smart quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This `‘y’` and this `“banana is ready to eat”`seem suspicious: wrong quotation marks

They should be `'y'` and `"banana is ready to eat"`

Compiler wants "normal" `""`quotation marks to identify strings and `''` for single characters

Comment: Worth adding in that to call methods and use member variables, one must first define methods and member variables. `mColor` and `setColor` are notably absent.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with **fuzzything44** and **Gian Paolo** comments. By the way, it should be pointed out that the current ISO C++ standard needs that the declaration of the `main` function have a type (`int main ()` for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You have so much wrong with your code, I doubt you've put any thought into it at all.

> $\fruit.cpp||In member function 'bool Banana::isRipe()':|
>   $\fruit.cpp|17|error: 'y' was not declared in this scope|

@Gian Paolo hit the nail on the head with [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323682/4143855) about incorrect quotation marks:

> Compiler wants "normal" `""` quotation marks to identify strings and `''` for single characters.

> $\fruit.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>   $\fruit.cpp|28|error: 'class Banana' has no member named 'setColor'|

You've literally not declared a function called `setColor`. Perhaps your `Fruit` class was meant to declare it (since all fruits presumably have a colour), or else your `Banana` class was meant to declare it, either way, you need to declare this function before you use it. On the same note, you've also failed to declare `mColor`:

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    void setColor(char col) { mColor = col };
protected:
    char mColor;
};
```

On this note, you probably want to use an `enum` for this since it makes far more sense than a `char`. What colour does `g` represent, or `b`?

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    enum class Color { Yellow, Red, Blue, Green };
    void setColor(Color c) { mColor = c; }
protected:
    Color mColor;
};
```

> $\fruit.cpp|28|error: 'y' was not declared in this scope|
>   $\fruit.cpp|30|error: expected ';' before 'is'|

Because you've failed to use the correct quotes around the character, the compiler assumes it's a variable. You need to use single quotes:

```
if (mColor == 'y')
```

However, if you use the `enum` as specified above, it will flow more logically into:

```
if (mColor == Color::Yellow)
```

> $\fruit.cpp|30|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
>   $\fruit.cpp|33|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|

You're either not `using namespace std` or not including `iostream.h`, but I'm going to wager a guess and say both. You need to include the files where `std::cout` and `std::endl` are declared, and specify the namespace they come from:

```
#include <iostream> // cout, endl
...
std::cout << "banana is ready to eat" << std::endl;
```

Notice also I've changed the quotes to double-quotations for a string literal.

It's worth mentioning two more things:
1. It makes no sense to inherit an empty class, like you are with `Fruit`.
2. As @EuGENE [points out in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323974/4143855), you need to specify a return type for all functions, `main()` inclusive! C++, unlike C, won't assume you mean to return an `int` by default:

```
int main()
```

My advice is to take more care in the future: Go slower, compile more frequently, and read what the compiler is telling you are errors.